# How to avoid from going to mail box when the data contains '@' sign in href link of display tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, displaytag

How to stop the browser from going to mail box when the link contains '@' sign.

```
<display:column class="aligncenter" style="font-style: italic;"
                        property="conditions" sortable="true" title="Terms & Conditions"
                        autolink="true" href="javascript: openWindow('#')" paramId="pid"
                        paramProperty="pid">
                    </display:column>

function openWindow(pid) {
    pid = pid.substring(0, pid.length - 1);
    var url = "conditionpopup" + pid;
    var a = navigator.appName;
    if (a == "Netscape" || a == "Crome") {
        var w = screen.width / 2.3;
        var h = screen.height / 1.3;
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
        window.open(url, 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
                + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
                + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
    } else {
        var w = screen.width / 2.3;
        var h = screen.height / 1.5;
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
        window.open(url, 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
                + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
                + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
    }

}
```

When the data contains '@' sign it go to the mail box which i dont want I want it to got to the page i am sending

Comment: Define _mail box_, do you mean it opens the default email client?

Comment: Could you please provide an example url that you are trying to pass?

Comment: there are some data coming from the database in the page for which i want a link to open a pop up so i used a javascript function to open a new window. But when @ sign comes in the link it reads as a email address whereas i need it to send it to the particular controller

Comment: Yes, this was already detailed in the question. Can you give an example for this kind of link? I see that you pass GET vars but they don't seem to contain @, so where does the @ comes from and what's it's functioniality?

Comment: Example if i am getting "something@something" data for the particular display tag column it should not open the email box but it should open the new window

Comment: What do you expect the newly opened window to contain?

Comment: I have some other page to open when clicked on that link. when the data contains @ it opens the outlook email but not the pop up. I want to open the popup what ever data that link contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **autolink="true**" in **display colum tag**.......

Answer (score 1):

Please, replace this:

```
if (a == "Netscape" || a == "Crome") {
    var w = screen.width / 2.3;
    var h = screen.height / 1.3;
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    window.open(url, 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
            + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
            + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
} else {
    var w = screen.width / 2.3;
    var h = screen.height / 1.5;
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    window.open(url, 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
            + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
            + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
}
```

With this:

```
var h = screen.height / 1.5;
if (a == "Netscape" || a == "Crome") {
    var h = screen.height / 1.3;
}
var w = screen.width / 2.3;
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
window.open(url, 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
        + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
        + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
```

[Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in programming.

Now, using this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.nl#@test', 'condtionpopup', "width=" + 500 + ", height=" + 500
        + ", top=" + 50 + ", left=" + 50
        + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
```

I'm getting a perfectly fine page to popup. no mail applications. Using my email address as url just opens a page that tells me the address ins't found, since a email address isn't a valid url.

If you want to show your data in the new window, you should do something like this:

```
// Open a blank page
myWindow = window.open('', 'condtionpopup', "width=" + w + ", height=" + h
        + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left
        + ", resizable=no, titlebar=0,dialog=yes,location=no");
myWindow.document.write(url);
// Write your url (or other data) to this page.
```

Comment: I have a outlook in my system when there is a data containing @ sign it opens the outlook

Comment: @ShrikantVenne, did you try that last piece of code I suggested?

Comment: @ShrikantVenne: How do you mean _"Does not work"_? Are you getting any errors?
It works just fine here.

Comment: i have a data coming from data base the following is the data dg@"'cdsfgQW Details:This offer.... and as i am using display tag this data is coming in a link. when clicked on it it is resend to the controller having request mapping with conditionpopup which fetches the data from the database and shows it in the popup. But when i am clicking on this data it opens the outlook mail with dg@ in the to mail section

Comment: I am not sending @ data in the url but its the data i am getting from the database which i am using as a link.